# Setting up diskless workstation for multiple clients

Tags: linux

I have mostly everything working except I'm not sure how to handle /var. If I set R/W on the kernel parameter, everything works as expected.

```
append initrd=/images/fedora/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic.nfs root=/dev/nfs rw nfsroot=10.129.1.113:/admin/linux/fedora/root
```

However, I don't want that, I want each workstation to have its own `/tmp` and `/var`. What options do I have? The issue I'm currently facing is that Ubuntu is expecting existing directories inside `/var/lib`. I've added a line in my fstab for `/var/lib` but since it's not already there, Gnome refuses to boot.

Here's my `fstab` file.

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
/dev/nfs       /               nfs    defaults          1       1
tmpfs       /dev        tmpfs   defaults    0   0
tmpfs            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults        0       0
tmpfs           /var/run        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
tmpfs            /var/lock       tmpfs   defaults        0       0
tmpfs           /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
#tmpfs           /var/lib        tmpfs   defaults        0       0
```

Comment: fat clients or thin?  The Ubuntu wiki covers both.

Comment: fat clients, their workstations. devs are being forced to convert to windows desktops and some refuse to run windows.

Answer (score 1):

According to the FHS specifications, /var/lib/misc is required to exist. See http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days of Sun workstations it was common practice to build a system with a small disk that had swap, root, temporary areas and maybe `/usr` on it.  Then, large shared areas such as `/home` could be mounted via NFS.  Sometimes this configuration was called a 'dataless' workstation.

You may want to start with a basic O/S build locally on your machines.  Once this is set up you can trivially clone it - pretty much all configuration can be done via DHCP.  Then, all the clients mount the same shared areas.  This approach also saves on a bit of network traffic.